# Help with JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

I have the json in following format.

```
[{"tag":{"name":"& Awards","id":142}},{"tag":{"name":"& Bisexual Bars","id":207}},{"tag":{"name":"& Clubs","id":40}},{"tag":{"name":"& Imaging","id":1188}}}
```

and am using the following code

```
$("#tags_name").autocomplete({
  source: "/companies/autocomplete_tags2.json",
  width: 320,
  dataType: 'json',
  highlight: false,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 300,
  parse: function(data) {
    var array = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i < data.tag.length; i++){
      array[i] = {data: data.tag[i], value: data.tag[i].value, result: data.tag[i].id };
    }
    return array;
  }
});
```

when i load the page the error i get is "newUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

What am i missing here?

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parse function is wrong for the JSON you have. You have an array of Objects in your JSON.

It should be something like

```
  parse: function(data) {
    var array = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
      array[i] = {data: data[i].tag, value: data[i].tag.name, result: data[i].tag.id };
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed part of the problem.

Comment: 'It seems that the json i am getting is not the correct mime type.

    def autocomplete_tags2
        items = Tag.find(:all, :select => "name, id")
        items.map! do |item| { :label => item.name, :value => item.id } end
        render :json => items.to_json
    end'